# how to add multiple confirmation mail receipents in campaign monitor api used in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I send the mail to the list of recipients. After that the confirmation mail is send to single person using campaign monitor api.But I want to send the confirmation mail to two or more recipients. could you please answer for this one.

like this:
    send = campaign.send!({ :campaignID => campaign.campaignID, :confirmationEmail => @email.from_email, :sendDate => 'Immediately' })

how can i change it for multi recipients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Campaign Monitor supports sending multiple campaign confirmations, however you can simply swap out the single email address for an email forwarder on your server which goes to multiple recipients.